# Hover over one DIV to zoom another DIV

Tags: css, zooming

I am not sure if this is a simple task to accomplish but I've had no success so far.

Let me explain the problem a little so that you understand what's going on.

The `body` element contains one `div` which contains a `background` that covers the entire window. I want this very big `div` to contain a smaller one somewhere in the middle. A transparent one. So whenever I would hover over the invisible `div` the parent would zoom from there.

This is me trying to accomplish a CSS zoom effect in a certain area of a picture. Whenever I leave the entire invisible div I want the huge background to return to its original zoom.

Here's some code.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="indexPage" class="indexPage">
            <div id="indexInvisible" class="indexInvisible"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.indexPage {
    background: url("map.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    transition: transform .2s;
```

}

```
.indexPage > .indexInvisible {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background: black;
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto;

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is the code i have at the moment. I am trying to zoom upon hovering on an invisible div. The invisible div marks the area on the "map" where the zoom should work. Once you leave that area the map returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

-> please update css into your css file

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
 body {
   line-height: 1.5;
   font-family: Arial, Tahoma;
   font-size: 12px;
}
.indexPage {
  background: url("map.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;        
}
.indexPage > .indexInvisible {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: black;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform .2s;
  -webkit-transition: transform .2s;
  -moz-transition: transform .2s;
  -ms-transition: transform .2s;
}
.indexPage:hover .indexInvisible {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="indexPage" class="indexPage">
            <div id="indexInvisible" class="indexInvisible"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for

Comment: please tell me more specific you want?

Comment: This zooms in the black div. I did manage this myself. Tho this black div will later not be visible. So the image behind it should zoom.

Comment: The black div is just there to mark the area in which the zoom effect should work. Aproximetly anyway. So once the user leaves that black area the map that is the bigger image should return to normal.

Comment: The point of all this is that ill be reading the coordonates of the mouse later on width js and move the origin point exactly where the mouse is. So when the user leaves that black area the js function will not fire anymore therefor the map will return to its normal size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `background-image:inherit` on the inner div and leverage `background-size` on hover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.map {
  width: 860px;
  height: 480px;
  background-image: url(https://www.homesinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1.jpg);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  ;
}

.zoomer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: inherit;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  background-size: 125% 125%;
  transition: background-size .5s ease;
  background-position: center center;
}

.zoomer:hover {
  background-size: 150% 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="zoomer"></div>
</div>
```